# Convergence problem in different norms

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

We remember the definition of strong convergence of a sequence in $B(H)$ for $H$ a Hilbert space: $a_n\rightarrow a$ iff $\left\|a_nx-ax\right\|\rightarrow0$ for all $x\in H$. In general norm convergence implies strong convergence, but the converse isn't true in general. But it seems to be special cases: Let $(a_n)$ a sequence in $B(H)$ which converges strongly to an operator $a\in B(H)$. Furthermore assume that $b$ is a compact operator. The claim is that the sequence $(a_nb)$ converges in norm (operator norm) to $ab$. I can't find a good reason of estimation to conclude that this should be true. Moreover if we take the sequence $(ba_n)$ then the conclusion that this converges to $ba$ isn't true. I think you have to use projections to find the counterexample, but more interesting is the question why $(a_nb)$ well converges. Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: A hint: show that strong convergence implies uniform convergence on compact sets.  (It will help to know that strongly convergent sequences are bounded in norm, which comes from the uniform boundedness principle.)

Comment: The last fact i proved already and it really follows directly from Banach-Steinhaus. And: yes i thought already that such a fact should be true but i can't make it concrete enough to make a good proof of this.

Comment: Another approach: show this is tru for rank one operators, then for finite dimensional operators, and finally for compact operators. Soon I'll give a reference.

Comment: If you're familiar with the proof of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem, the same device is used there.  The key is that a set of operators bounded in norm is equicontinuous.  And the relevant step in Arzela-Ascoli shows that an equicontinuous sequence converging pointwise also converges uniformly on compact sets.

Comment: Use second lemma of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529925/question-about-adjoint-map-and-strong-operator-topology-sot) with $S_n=1_H$

Comment: Incidentally, this fact also holds if $H$ is replaced by a Banach space, but @Norbert's proof won't generalize, because not all Banach spaces have the [approximation property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah your right. One have the compact image of the unit ball and therefore finite subcover which implies the convergence. Thus only the counterexample has to be found :)