# Compact operator and a sot convergent sequence of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

The following is an exercise of Conway's operator theory: [image]

I proved all parts of this exercise except $\|KT_n\| \to 0$. I can easily prove $\|KT_n^*\|\to 0$, but do not have any idea to prove $\|KT_n\| \to 0$. Plase give me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: May be [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529925/question-about-adjoint-map-and-strong-operator-topology-sot/529993#529993) can help

Comment: @userNaN: but this shows $\|KT_n^*\|\to 0$.

Comment: This seems to be wrong. Consider $T_n:=B^n$, where $B$ is the "backward shift" on $\ell^2$, and $K=e_0\otimes e_0^*$.

Comment: @Etienne : What is $K=e_0\otimes e_0^*$? What is the meaning of $*$ ?

Comment: $e_0^*$ is the $0$-th coordinate functional; if you prefer, this is $e_0$... So $e_O\otimes e_0^* (x)=\langle x,e_0\rangle \, e_0$.

Comment: @Etienne : Yeas, you are right. Thanks.